# Can't print data from struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

My goal here is to print student data contain in `struct`

My question is why i unable to print out data from struct?

Here is my code:

```c
typedef struct _STUDENT{
    char *fullname;
    int ID;
    float scores[6];
} STUDENT;
void input(STUDENT* student){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nInput Student Fullname: ");
    scanf("%s", &student->fullname);
    printf("\nInput ID: ");
    scanf("%s",&student->ID);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        printf("\nInput point for course %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f",&student[i].scores);
    }
    
}
void output(STUDENT* student){
    
    printf("\nStudent Fullname: %s", student->fullname);
    printf("\nStudent ID: %d", student->ID);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        printf("\nStudent Score: %f", student[i].scores);   
    }
    
}

int main(){
    
    STUDENT* students;
    int size;
    printf("Enter number of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    
    students = (STUDENT*)calloc(size,sizeof(STUDENT));
    
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){

        input(students+i);
    }

    
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        output(students+i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
Student Fullname:?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
Student ID: 50
Student Score: 0.000000
Student Score: 0.000000
Student Score: 0.000000
Student Score: 0.000000
Student Score: 0.000000
Student Score: 0.000000
```

under the output funtion i try to print out some data but none of it been print

Comment: You can't `scanf` a string into `&student->fullname`, which is the address of zero pointer (zeroed via calloc). You have to allocate space for a string before you read into it, and ideally use `fgets` rather than `scanf` to avoid potential buffer overrun problems.

Comment: Use `-Wall` as a compiler option to enable many warnings, including mis-typed arguments to printf and scanf (assuming you're using gcc or clang).

Comment: You are attempting to scan the ID as a string, but you are providing storage for an `int`, and reading the result back as an `int`.

Comment: @PaulHankin: You can specify the maximum field width using `%<maxlen>s` to prevent a buffer overflow using `scanf`

Comment: `&student[i].scores` is the address of the score array belonging to the `i`th student.  You appear to want `&student->scores[i]`, instead. (Alternatively, `student->scores + i` means the same thing.)

Comment: `static const no_scores = sizeof ((struct _STUDENT *)0)->scores / *((struct _STUDENT *)0)->scores;` is 6; if you replace 6 by `no_scores` in your functions, you could change the 6 in the definition without breaking any of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why i unable to print out data from struct?

In part, the student data are just not what you expect, on account of numerous errors in your `input()` function.  You could have discovered this for yourself by running the program under control of a debugger, and your compiler might have warned you about several of the errors, at least if you turned up the warning level.  *Always* pay attention to compiler warnings.

Issues with your `input()` function include:

- Do not `fflush()` the standard input.  Flushing is about *output*, not input.  If `fflush(stdin)` happens to produce an effect that you find desirable then that is not portable.  If you want to ignore some input then *read* and discard it.

  As long as you are using `scanf` or `fscanf` for input, however, be aware that most field directives skip leading whitespace, including newlines.  In that case, however, be aware also that these functions are difficult to use correctly.  You may be better served by `fgets()` combined with `sscanf()`, though that's not a cure-all.
- You do not check the return values of your `scanf()` calls.  This is not in itself an error *per se*, but it means that the program will not recognize input errors or malformed input (relative to your sequence of `scanf` calls).
- This ...

  > ```
  >     scanf("%s", &student->fullname);
  > ```

  ... attempts to read the name into the representation of a pointer.  Undefined behavior results if the name (with terminating null) is longer than  the representation of a pointer (probably either four or eight bytes).  You probably meant to read the data into the location to which the pointer points:

  ```
      scanf("%s", student->fullname);
  ```

  ... but that is problematic too, because the pointer does not point to valid storage.  You could solve the latter problem (with the corrected code) by declaring the `fullname` member as an array instead of a pointer, in which case you would want to take care to avoid overrunning the length of that array.  Alternatively, you could read the name into a local temporary array, and then  allocate a copy for the student to point to:

  ```
  char temp[1024];
  int result = scanf("%1023s", temp);
  if (result != 1) /* ... handle input failure ... */;
  student->fullname = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
  strcpy(student->fullname, temp);
  ```

  If you have a POSIX-compatible `strdup()` function, then you could use that instead of the explicit `malloc` and `strcpy`.
- Also, "fullname" suggests a string that may contain space characters, but `%s` scans a *whitespace-delimited* string.  You may want a `%[` directive instead, but do note that that is one of the few directives that does not ignore leading whitespace.
- This ...

  > ```
  >     scanf("%s",&student->ID);
  > ```

  ... is wrong, because `&student->ID` is a pointer to `int`, whereas a `%s` requires a pointer to `char`.  Additionally, that will attempt to store the result as a string, not as an `int`.
- This ...

  > ```
  >             scanf("%f",&student[i].scores);
  > ```

  ... is wrong because you are passing a pointer to an array (of `float`), not a pointer to `float`.  That in itself probably would not cause an error in practice, but for `i != 0`, it is also a pointer to the wrong location.  `student[i].scores` is the `scores` array of the student at offset `i`, but you appear to want the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the scores array of the student at offset 0:

  ```
              scanf("%f", &student->scores[i]);
  ```

  An error analogous to this also appears in your `output()` function.

  Additionally, if you were checking then you might find that some or all of these calls were failing to scan anything.  With your current code, this would probably be the case when a three-part fullname was presented (for example, "Cento T. Programmer").

Comment: `Alternatively, you could read the name into a local temporary array, and then allocate a copy for the student to point to. `

I try to create temporary array and still can't seem to get it to run  can you show some example?

Comment: I have added some example code, @Cento, but note well that you need to correct *all* the issues described.  You might or might not see different output after correcting only some of them.